# After upgrade to 14.04 I get "You don't have permission to access /wiki/ on this server."

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, apache2, mediawiki

After dist-upgrade to 14.04 I get "You don't have permission to access /wiki/ on this server." for a MediaWiki installation with alias. `/w/index.php` is also failing.

So far I have seen a difference in configuration between 12.04 and 14.04 and I did

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo ln -s ../sites-available/000-default.conf .
```

This fixed other problems, but not the MediaWiki problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with a missing link:

```
cd /etc/apache2/conf-enabled
sudo ln -s ../conf-available/mediawiki.conf .
```

This made the wiki instance appear again.

Another error appeared after fixing the initial problem. This was due to change in MediaWiki database schema (if I understand correctly). I solved this with:

```
cd /var/lib/mediawiki/maintenance
sudo php update.php
```

As far as I can determine the wiki is now running ok.